# my sub navigation bar is visible when i hover over the navbar element itself but disappears when i hover over it

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made a  sub nav bar, and it disappears when I hover over it, I tried changing somethings but it still will disappear when I hover over the submenu itself. if anyone knows what I could do that would be really helpful.

code:

```
<header>
        <div class="containers">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">movies</a>
                       <ul class="sub-menu">  
                           <li><a href="MovieRecsPage.html" class="sub-menu-content-a">Recommended</a></li>
                           <li><a href="#" class="sub-menu-content-a">best rated movies</a></li>
                           <li><a href="#" class="sub-menu-content-a">Genre</a>
                               <ul class="dsub-menu">
                                   <li><a href="#" class="dsub-menu-content-a">Action</a></li>
                                   <li><a href="#" class="dsub-menu-content-a">adventure</a></li>
                                   <li><a href="#" class="dsub-menu-content-a">Comedy</a></li>
                                   <li><a href="#" class="dsub-menu-content-a">Sci-Fi</a></li>
                                   <li><a href="#" class="dsub-menu-content-a">Romance</a></li>
                                   <li><a href="#" class="dsub-menu-content-a">Animation</a></li>
                                   <li><a href="#" class="dsub-menu-content-a">Horror</a></li>
                                   <li><a href="#" class="dsub-menu-content-a">Fantasy</a></li>
                                   <li><a href="#" class="dsub-menu-content-a">Crime</a></li>
                                   <li><a href="#" class="dsub-menu-content-a">Drama</a></li>
                                   <li><a href="#" class="dsub-menu-content-a">Mystery</a></li>
                               </ul>
                           </li>
                       </ul>    
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">TV shows</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">watch list</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Oscar</a></li>                    
                <li><a href="RegisterLogInPage.html"><small>Sign In</small></a></li>
            </ul>  
           </nav>
            
        </div> 
    </header>
```

CSS:

```
    containers{
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

header{
    background-color: firebrick;
    height: 70px;
}

header::after{
    content: '';
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

img{
    float: left;
    padding: 10px 80px;
    height: 50px; 
    width: 150px;
}

nav{
    float: right;
    padding: 10px 55px;
}

nav ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

nav ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 70px;
    padding-top: 23px;
    position: relative;
}

nav ul li a{
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

nav a:hover{
    color: #191919;
}

nav a::before{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 5px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: black;
    
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 0%;
    
    transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
}

nav a:hover::before{
    width: 100%;
}

.sub-menu{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: indianred;
    width: 200%;
    height: 200px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    display: block;
    top: 60px;
    right: 0;
    left: -30px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: none;
}

.sub-menu li {
    color: #eee;
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 100%;
    left: -65px;
    padding: 15px 0;
    
}

nav ul li:hover ul.sub-menu{
   display: block;
}
```

**note:** the CSS code that I applied here doesn't contain the other submenu.
thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make the sub-menu appear on link `hover` like this

```
nav li:hover .sub-menu {
  display: block;
  background: #fff;
}
```

[Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/KaungKZ/pen/dypMmXp?editors=1100)

Comment: One thing more you also have to make menu's `height to 100%` otherwise as soon as the user moves the cursor down from the movies menu the cursor will no longer hover the movies menu nor it is hovering the sub-menu so the sub-menu will close.

Comment: Yeah I fixed the parent element to `height: 100%`

Comment: Please accept the answer if it helped your question.